# MySQL - Sum of digits of year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sum

I need to get the sum of digits of year in format `date`, for example `1997 = 1+9+9+7 = 26`. I have to do it in MySQL with `SELECT` only. I've tried to use `SUM` function, but it sums only years in a few rows.

Table name: list.

[image]

In phpMyAdmin, I'm executing the following command and getting the following results:

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have tried. And your table schema. This is too general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do arithmetics for this:

```
set @year = 1997;    
select 
    floor(@year / 1000) 
    + floor(@year % 1000 / 100) 
    + floor(@year % 100 / 10)
    + floor(@year % 10) res
```

Yields:

```
26
```

Starting from a `date` or `datetime` value, you can use `year()` to extract the year part first:

```
set @mydate = '1997-01-01';    
select 
    floor(year(@mydate) / 1000) 
    + floor(year(@mydate) % 1000 / 100) 
    + floor(year(@mydate) % 100 / 10)
    + floor(year(@mydate) % 10) res
```

Comment: But I have year in format date, not in integer. I've edited my question.

Comment: How can I output this result for each row of a table "list"?

Comment: @Clarity: just: `insert into list select floor(year(mydate) / 1000) + ... from mytable`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use something like this.
Result for `1997-01-01`

```
SELECT @result:=
    @First:= LEFT(year,1)+
    @Second:= SUBSTRING(year,2,1)+ 
    @Third:= SUBSTRING(year,3,1)+
    @forth:= SUBSTRING(year,4,1) 
FROM year;

    ---

    **Query #1**

    SELECT * FROM year;

| id  | year       | result |
| --- | ---------- | ------ |
| 1   | 1997-01-01 |        |
| 2   |            | 26     |

    ---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mrdoHYKBiRdB3NTDcpKKZE/2)

Comment: Your example is for year in "varchar(255)" but I need format "date" for year.

Comment: @Clarity I edited link, now its date. Works with date also, no difference.